# DataTables export options: strip html from table heads

Tags: javascript, datatables, export

I am using DataTables 1.10+. I need to remove some elements from the table heads, so they are not there in exported files (xml, pdf, print, ...).

In this [DataTables example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html), is shown how to do that with body data. The problem is that I can't do the same on header data.

```
  var buttonCommon = {
    'exportOptions': {
      'format': {
        'header': function( thead, data, start, end, display ) { //'header' instead of 'body'
          return thead.replace(/X/g, ''); //Trying to remove X in every th
        }
      }          
    }
  };
```

The PDF file shows only the table rows, without any `thead`.

What am I doing wrong? Should `header` function use other parameters?

I'm not able to find any documentation about `format` in datatables.net, only the example linked above.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It had to work, maybe you made a mistake elsewhere.

Try this:

```
var buttonCommon = {
    exportOptions : {
        format : {
            header : function (data, column, row) {
                return data.replace(/X/g, '');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name X</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

PDF result:

[image]

example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/3mf5yhv3/)

Comment: You are right, in my code `data` is returning html tags as well and it was somehow broken with the replacement (there is more to strip than I thought ^^'). Thanks for your help